# Adding newline between elements in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, newline

I'm beggining in XML and XSLT and I have a problem with adding a new line beetwen elements

Here's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<numbers>
    <person id="1">
        <phone>
         <phone_nr>111111111</phone_nr>
         <phone_nr>222222222</phone_nr>
        </phone>
    </person>
    <person id="2">
        <phone>
          <phone_nr>333333333</phone_nr>
            </phone>
    </person>
</numbers>
```

XSLT looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="numbers/person">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <td>
       <table>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it gives me this (with borders) :

```
111111111 222222222
333333333
```

but what I want is:

```
111111111
222222222
333333333
```

The problem is that XML must be like this and I don't know, how to creating a new line in XSLT.

Comment: Please post your expected result **as code**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are outputting HTML, so to do a "newline" you need to output a `<br>` tag. The problem you have at the moment is that you are outputting the text value of the `phone` element, which concatenates all the text nodes under it together. You really need to handle the child `phone_nr` nodes separately, with an `xsl:for-each` for example

```
   <td>
       <xsl:for-each select="phone/phone_nr">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
       </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="numbers/person">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <td>
           <xsl:for-each select="phone/phone_nr">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
           </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question without knowing what the **exact** output should be. Going just by what you showed us, the simplest way would be:

```
<xsl:template match="/numbers">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="person/phone/phone_nr">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```